# What is wrong with declaring *ptr=x after initialization of *ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, initialization, declaration

```
int x=10;
int *p;
p=&x;
int **pp=&p;
cout<<**pp<<"\n"<<*p<<"\n"<<pp<<"\n"<<&p<<"\n";
```

Things are going well in this above case but when I changed the way declaring pointer p:

```
int x=10;
int *p;
*p=x;
int **pp=&p;
cout<<**pp<<"\n"<<*p<<"\n"<<pp<<"\n"<<&p<<"\n";
```

It fails to give any output.
Why is that?

Comment: You're assigning a value to `*p` without first allocating space for it.

Comment: In the first example, you assign the address of `x` to `p`. In the other one, you assign the value of `x` to wherever `p` is currently pointing to (it points to nowhere)

Comment: *It fails to give any output. Why is that?* I suspect you either have not enabled your compiler warnings, or you've ignored the compiler's warnings.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
int *p;
p=&x;
```

assigns the adress of `x` to `p`.

This:

```
int *p;
*p=x;
```

Does something radically different. It dereferences `p` and assigns the value of `x` to the result. `p` is uninitialized. It does not point to an `int`. Hence, dereferencing `p` and trying to assing the value of `x` results in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

You are confusing the value of the pointer (the memory adress of an `int`) with what it points to (an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int *p;
> ```

Here, `p` is default initialised, and therefore it has an indeterminate value. It doesn't point to any object. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate pointer is undefined.

> ```
> *p=x;
> ```

Here, you read the indeterminate pointer value and attempt to indirect through it to access the value that isn't being pointed at. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
> p=&x;
> ```

This assigns `p` with a value, so that the value is no longer indeterminate. Since this new pointer value is valid, it is OK to indirect through it later (as long as the pointer remains valid).

Answer (score 0):

you define a pointer without allocating memory to it so it is a wild pointer and doesn't point to any part of memory